# Client side Hangout API

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I'm trying to create a project on top of Google Hangout. I'd like to analyze the written text from the participants. This happens on an external server and asynchronous. The clients sends the messages via REST to my external server.

My problem is that I don't know how I can push the results back to the Hangout clients and using it in my project. Is it possible to send the result back via a Hangout client/session id?
I think it's a bad solution to provide a server side API and calling them ever X seconds...

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/shared-state)

> Hangouts come with a shared-state object, one per Hangout. The shared
>   state object contains data that is kept up-to-date with every instance
>   of the Hangout client that is running your app. The object is a
>   regular JavaScript object with paired key/value strings.
>
> You can set a key/value pair and that change will be distributed to
>   every instance of the Hangout client that is running your app.

i think this is what you are looking for.